# cypress actions - inicializar componente en un beforeEach / before hook

Tags: javascript, testing

Tengo el siguiente codigo en un archivo index.js

```
Cypress.Commands.add('component', (name) => {
    let log = Cypress.log({
        'displayName': 'component',
        'name': name
    });
    cy
        .window({ log: false })
        .then($win => {
            const component = name === 'root' ? $win.app : $win.app.$children.find(e => e.$vnode.tag.includes(name))
            log.set({
                consoleProps: () => {
                    return { component };
                }
            });
            return component;
        });
})
```

Los test funcionan bien pero tengo que llamar el metodo cy.controller en cada uno de los test (it).

Me gustaria ininicializarlo una unica vez en un beforeEach y luego utilizarlo siempre en cada uno de los test

Como se puede hacer eso?

Gracias!

Comment: Hola Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español para formular una buena pregunta porfavor revisa nuestra documentacion https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Para solucionar el problema la solucion era inicializar la variable del componente en la seccion describe y luego inicializar el componente en el hook beforeEach de la siguiente forma

```
cy.component('Login').then(component => login = component)
```

Si a alguien mas le sirve